# Find the set of columns which are not co related to each other in a dataset

Tags: pandas, numpy

There is a huge dataset in which I have to list out the columns which are not co-related to each other.

I was able to find the columns which were co-related to each other but how to exclude them

Comment: You should read how to post a question, since we can't really help you without some code or data to work around, some [ressources](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) before posting

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In general the way you exclude columns from your data is as follows:

```py
df.drop(columns_to_exclude, axis=1)
```